# Excel formula - calculation where date falls between 2 dates in different columns

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

I have a table with a "start date" column and "end date" column as detailed below.

I am trying to insert a formula to populate a dynamic calendar with data from the table for the records where the specified dates falls between the "start date" and "end date" columns. The formulas dont seem to be calculating correctly.

The formulas I need are as follows:

- COUNT - Where date specified falls between "start date" column and "end date" column and "Occupied" column = "Y". The Formula below seems to calculate correctly but is it excluding the specified date?
  `=COUNT(dependency_tool_table[Start Date])-(SUMPRODUCT(--(dependency_tool_table[Start Date]>I$6)+--(dependency_tool_table[End Date]<I$6)))`
- SUM - "Number of staff Required" column where date specified falls between "start date" column and "end date" column. The formula below should be correct but it doesnt seem to be correct.
  `= SUMIFS(dependency_tool_table[Number of Staff Required],dependency_tool_table[Start Date], ">="&H$6, dependency_tool_table[End Date], "<="&H$6)&" Staff Required")`
- RETURN ALL MATCHING RECORDS - Where date specified falls between "start date" column and "end date" column and "Occupied" column = "Y". The formula below should be correct but it doesnt seem to be correct.
  `=IFERROR(IF(H$6="","",TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, IF((dependency_tool_table[Start Date]>=H$6)*(dependency_tool_table[End Date]<=H$6)*(dependency_tool_table[Occupied]="Y")," "& dependency_tool_table[Forename]&" "&dependency_tool_table[Surname], ""))),"")`

[image: data table]

[formula 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNqCl.png)

[formula 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Bcy.png)

Comment: "The formula below should be correct but it doesnt seem to be correct." - please describe what you would expect the correct result.

Comment: The formulas aren't all returning the correct values. 

If the date parameter used is H$6 (date in the cell is 01/09/2022) for all 3 formulas I would expect the following.
- COUNT = 6
- SUM = 6
- MATCHING RECORDS - First 6 names in the table

Comment: - COUNT - =COUNTIFS(dependency_tool_table[Start Date], "<="&H$6, dependency_tool_table[End Date], ">="&H$6, dependency_tool_table[Occupied], "Y")

- SUM - =SUM(dependency_tool_table[Number of Staff Required])-SUMPRODUCT(--(dependency_tool_table[Start Date]>H$6)+--(dependency_tool_table[End Date]<H$6), dependency_tool_table[Number of Staff Required])

- MATCHING RECORDS - =CONCAT(FILTER(dependency_tool_table[Forename]&" "&dependency_tool_table[Surname],
(dependency_tool_table[Start Date]<=H$6)*
(dependency_tool_table[End Date]>=H$6)*
(dependency_tool_table[Occupied]="Y"),
"")

Comment: Formulas above seem to work

Comment: "seem to work": You should be able to tell wether the result *is correct or not*. Do some tests - maybe by implementing intermediate steps, e.g. create a helper column, that only checks, if  the date from H6 is within the rows Start/End Date - returning true or false per row ... then you can use that column for your summary formulas.